# JPQL query with ManyToMany

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to execute this following JPQL :

```
@Query("select o from Offre o where o.typeContrat.titre=:a or o.ville.nomVille=:b or o.competences.libelleCompetance = :c")
    public Page<Offre> offresSearch(@Param("a") String type, @Param("b") String location, @Param("c") String competence,Pageable pageable);
```

and this is my Offre entity :

```
@Entity
public class Offre implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CODE_OFFRE")
    private Long codeOffre;
    private String titre;
    @Lob
    private String description;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="codeContratType")
    private TypeContrat typeContrat;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="OFFRE_COMP",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CODE_OFFRE"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CODE_COMPETENCE"))
    private List<Competence> competences;

    // Getters and setters
```

and this is my Competence entity :

```
    @Entity
    public class Competence implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CODE_COMPETENCE")
    private Long codeCompetence;
    private String libelleCompetance;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="competences")
    private Collection<Offre> offres;

    // Getters, Setters

    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Offre> getOffres() {
        return offres;
    }
    @JsonSetter
    public void setOffres(Collection<Offre> offres) {
        this.offres = offres;
    }
}
```

but when I run my application I'm getting this error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException:
>   illegal attempt to dereference collection
>   [offre0_.code_offre.competences] with element property reference
>   [libelleCompetance] [select o from com.capValue.Rekrute.entities.Offre
>   o where o.typeContrat.titre=:a or o.ville.nomVille=:b or
>   o.competences.libelleCompetance = :c]     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
>   ...

Comment: You may need to explicitly join instead of drilling down through the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot navigate in the query on a ToMany relation. You must use JOIN:

```
select o from Offre o join o.competences c 
where o.typeContrat.titre = :a or o.ville.nomVille = :b or c.libelleCompetance = :c
```